# WIX conditional SQL script execution is not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am creating a new WIX installer. The installation is based on the customer's existing database. At the very first installation I have the information of the already installed features only in the database. So I have to query theese features from it and the installer shouldn't execute its activation scripts. Every feature has a property and from a custom action I set theese properties but the conditional SQL script execution is not working. I've created a sample wxs source file. Could you help me what is wrong with it?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' xmlns:sql='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension'>
        
    <!-- https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/product.html -->
    <Product Id='BC075295-7BB8-4B82-89AC-3F81681130CC' Name='XXX' UpgradeCode='4AD0BCB8-B1BB-4FE1-ABEE-58E93321AAC5' Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='XXX'>
        <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="XXX Installer" InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252'/> 
        <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Andoc.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />     

        <Binary Id="WixCustomActions" SourceFile="CustomAction.CA.dll" /> 
        <Binary Id="sqlScriptBinaryKey" SourceFile="insert.sql" />

        <CustomAction Id="SetExecuteScriptCondition" BinaryKey="WixCustomActions" DllEntry="SetExecuteScriptCondition" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

        <Property Id="EXECUTE_SCRIPT" Value="NO" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="XXX" />
        </Directory>

        <Component Id="componentSqlScript" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="1af938ef-6788-a0e1-2370-a6c2620c9dCC">
        
            <Condition>EXECUTE_SCRIPT = "YES"</Condition>

            <sql:SqlDatabase Id="db" Database="[DATABASE_NAME]" Server="[DATABASE_SERVER]" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="no" ContinueOnError="no">
                <sql:SqlScript Id="SqlScriptId" BinaryKey="sqlScriptBinaryKey" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" ContinueOnError="no" />
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
            
            <CreateFolder />
        </Component>

        <Feature Id="feature" Title="xxx" Description="xxx" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="componentSqlScript" />
        </Feature>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>        
            <Custom Action='SetExecuteScriptCondition' Before='InstallInitialize' />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <UI>    
            <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />  
        </UI>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

My custom action looks like this.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetExecuteScriptCondition(Session session)
{
    session["EXECUTE_SCRIPT"] = "YES"; 
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

In the log I see that the EXECUTE_SCRIPT property value is 'YES' but the insert.sql script is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to solve this problem by creating a subfeature to the sql component and moving the component condition to the feature level. And instead of InstallExecuteSequence I execute my custom action in InstallUISequence.

```
<Feature Id="feature" Title="xxx" Description="xxx" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Level="1">
    <Feature Id="feature_script" Title="script" Description="script" Display="hidden" Level="1" >
        <Condition Level="0">EXECUTE_SCRIPT = "NO"</Condition>                          
        <Condition Level="1">EXECUTE_SCRIPT = "YES"</Condition>
        <ComponentRef Id="componentSqlScript" />                
    </Feature>          
</Feature>      

<InstallUISequence>     
    <Custom Action='SetExecuteScriptCondition' Before='LaunchConditions' />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

`InstallInitialize` is too late, as the condition for your component 'componentSqlScript' is evaluated during costing. That's the reason setting that property didn't appear to work.

You need to schedule your action before 'CostInitialize', sequence it in both UI and Execute sequences (since the UI sequence doesn't necessarily run, and if costing is also preformed in the UI sequence then the execute sequence will be too late). You should add `Execute="firstSequence"` to your `CustomAction` element, and you should add `Secure="yes"` to your `Property` element, to prevent running code excessively and prevent issues where public property values aren't always set to the execute sequence.